# Помогите разобраться с кодом Python (фреймворк dash)

Tags: python, веб-программирование, sql-server, csv, plotly

Скопировала [код с оффициального сайта фреймворка Plotly Dash.](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload)

Код позволяет закачать csv файл на html страницу и просмотреть его. Мне не нужно его показывать на странице, а необходимо выполнять некоторые преобразования с ним и далее закачать в БД ms SQL. Вы можете пожалуйста подсказать, какую часть кода мне нужно поменять, что не поломать кнопку и страницу в целом.

Код

```
import base64
import datetime
import io

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table

import pandas as pd


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])


def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        ),

        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
              [State('upload-data', 'filename'),
               State('upload-data', 'last_modified')])
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Одна из частей кода, которую нужно добавить:

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv('My_file.csv', sep = ',')
replace_map = {"Column": {True: "Value_1", False: "Value_2"}}
res = (csv_file.groupby([csv_file["Column"].str.contains(r"[^-\d]"))
       .sum()
       .reset_index()
       .replace(replace_map))
```

Comment: Всё для ответа на вопрос должно быть в самом вопросе, а не по ссылкам

Comment: добавила код в описание

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал сюда:

```
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        send_to_db(df)
    except Exception as e:
```

Чтоб не поломать -- git.

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш ответ, буду сейчас пробовать.